# Ag-grid to show both loading and no data overlays

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am working with Ag-grid and I found that only one of loading and no data overlays can be shown at a time.

My situation is that at the beginning, I have no data and a loading observable. I subscribe to that observable and manually call the grid api to setup the loading but it was later replaced by no data overlay due to the grid.

Is there a way to have both running (which I can use css for the loading overlay to hide the no data)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around, I found that adding `showLoadingOverlay()` to `onRowDataChanged` event solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add your own overlay with desired condition in `*ngIf` and style it as you want?

Comment: yes I can do that, but I think it would be neat to have aggrid api handle this